# Spam email is slipping through Gmail's filter

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

Starting last week, I started receiving a bunch of spam email to to my main Gmail account.  It is super annoying and I get around three per day right now. I mark each email as spam but I keep getting more. I haven't had this problem in years.
I can't make a filter because they are being sent from different addresses and domains.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: You're doing the right thing. Once in a while spammers glom on to some technique that gets their junk past spam filters. At least until the filters get better. Once a year or so I see a little storm like this; it doesn't take long until the filters get better and you don't see it any more.

Answer (score 1):

My company Gmail account was once spammed by nasty things about viagra and so on. I couldn't really resolve it at first but here's what I did:

1. Click "Create a filter" at the top of the Gmail window, to the right of the search bar;
2. Enter the modified email address in the "To" field, and click "Next";
3. Select the appropriate action, such as marking the message read, sending it straight into the archive, applying an identifiable label or deleting it;
4. Click "Create Filter" to create the filter;
5. Create additional filters for each modified email address.

Also, you check [this article](http://www.techyv.com/questions/anti-spam-my-e-mail).

Hope this helps.

Comment: "I can't make a filter because they are being sent from different addresses and domains."